# Show all updated files of a particular branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

How to display all updated file name on a particular branch.
I have created a feature/[branchName] and after many commits on it,
I would like to display all updated files from the first commit to the last one, on that branch.

Comment: What do you consider to be the first commit? Have you considered using `git diff`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox my first commit in the branch

Comment: can you clarify please what 'all my modifications' means, and how e.g. `git diff origin/master` does _not_ do what you want?

Comment: @AD7six thanks i can see only updated file of all commits into my branch with  ```git diff origin/master ```

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the branch:

```
$ git checkout <branch_name>
```

Show commit logs with full diff:

```
$ git log -p
```

Comment: git log -p didn't display only branch commits, it show me all project commit in chronological order.   ```git diff --name-only master...``` or ```git diff origin/master``` solve the issue, thanks